# Не работает checkboxcolumn c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Сделал код.
Он выделяет как на скриншоте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как исправить чтобы выделялось нормально (галочки ставились)?
Как передать "выделенное" кнопке?

```
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                if (chk.Selected == true)
                {
                    chk.Selected = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    chk.Selected = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

Исправил код: Теперь выделяется галочками как и нужно, но выделение не снимается. Ошибка?

```
if (chk.Selected == true)
                    {
                        chk.Value = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chk.Value = true;
                    }
```

Comment: Свойство `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.Selected` отвечает именно за выделение ячейки, что, собственно у Вас и происходит. За установку галочки отвечает свойство `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.Value`. Если я правильно помню

Comment: Исправил (добавил код в вопрос): теперь галочками выделяется как нужно, но не снимаются по обратному действию. Что-то не так сделал?

Comment: `chk.Value = !Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value);` - без всяких `if`ов.

Comment: Да. Заработало. Спасибо. Можете оформить ваш комментарий ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте текущее значение для установки нового:

```
chk.Value = !Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value);
```